# How to differentiate null response from timeout using Axon Framework in Java

Tags: java, cqrs, axon

I am sending a command and expecting a result via **CommandGateway.sendAndWait(Object command, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)** method :

```
 Greeting greeting = commandGateway.sendAndWait(new GenericCommandMessage<GetGreetingCommand>(cmd), 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

There are 3 possible outcomes of the above call:

**1)** Return a non null object.

**2)** Return a null object (via business logic from my **@CommandHandler** that queries a DB and doesn't find what I was looking for)

**3)** Return a null object (returned by Axon framework in case timeout is reached)

I need to implement a way to differentiate between points 2) and 3) so that I can return NOT_FOUND or REQUEST_TIMEOUT statuses accordingly. Do you have any recommendations on how to model this ?

One way that I though of was to add a status field in Greeting (my model object) and in case the **@CommandHandler** receives nothing from DB I would return a dummy Greeting object with status = -1 (meaning NOT_FOUND), but this solution would mean adding flags to model objects only to differentiate between framework flows and I don't think this is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

The default CommandGateway doesn't allow for this distinction. However, it is possible to define your own gateway, by providing an interface to the `GatewayProxyFactory.createGateway()` method. Create an instance by passing the `CommandBus` that the gateway should send messages through in the constructor.

This mechanism allows you to define the behavior that you want, for each method. If you declare a `TimeoutException`, that exception will be thrown instead of a null return value being returned. If the timeout is the same for each invocation, you can event replace the timeout value parameters (int/long and timeunit) with an annotation.

Check out the javadoc on the [GatewayProxyFactory](http://www.axonframework.org/apidocs/2.4/org/axonframework/commandhandling/gateway/GatewayProxyFactory.html) for more details.